# Django Admin select_related issue

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I'm trying to `select_related` for a bunch of assets in the Django admin.
These assets are tied to a product, which in turn has a separate Company and Category model. These are both a foreign key from product, to the respective model.
I defined the string method like so in the Product class:

```
def __str__(self):
    if self.company:
        return f"{self.category.name} | {self.company.name} | {self.name}"
    return f"{self.category.name} | {self.name}"
```

However, when I check debug toolbar in the Django admin, I see that a bunch of extra queries are made because of this.

```
products\models.py in __str__(53)
  return f"{self.category.name} | {self.company.name} | {self.name}"
```

I have the following `get_queryset` method defined in the ModelAdmin:

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super().get_queryset(request).select_related(
        'product', 
        'product__category', 
        'product__company')
    if request.user.is_superuser or request.user.is_staff:
        return qs
    return qs.filter(user=request.user)
```

Is there a fix for this? Am I doing it wrong?

### Edit*

I have narrowed down the issue to Django admin's list filter.
The `list_filter` allows filtering by product, which in turn displays it's `__str__` method.

I have decided to just remove the product from the list filter.
Would still be nice to have a fix provided for any future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) instead of `select_related` as it is more versatile than `select_related` and can be used to prefetch related fields at any level of depth so:

```py
def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super().get_queryset(request).prefetch_related(
        'product', 
        'product__category', 
        'product__company')
    if request.user.is_superuser or request.user.is_staff:
        return qs
    return qs.filter(user=request.user)
```

Comment: This did not help me unfortunately, same result.

Comment: @nigel239 Does it also give extra queries? Did you check?

Comment: @nigel239 I think you need to add a custom method in `ModelAdmin` class instead of using it in `__str__()` method.

Comment: I checked, the output is pretty much the same (Queries hover around 310-330). I have however narrowed down the issue. I will update the question.